# how to index by email in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

how to use email address as key?

```
Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

What is the best way of indexing by email address in `firebase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the best way of handing the dot in email addresses is to replace them with another character. The easiest way I've found is just to use a comma (,).

```
function escapeEmail(email) {
    return (email || '').replace('.', ',');
}

function unescapeEmail(email) {
    return (email || '').replace(',', '.');
}
```

This fiddle shows how to index emails and has the escaping code:
http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/HLUc5/

If you want to read up on indexing and querying there is this article as well:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html