# How to ensure clean Firebase child paths?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a list of data that I'm using to create a Firebase data structure.

I got the error

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "Bitex.la". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

I understand the error message.

I'm wondering what the cleanest way is to ensure valid child path names? Is there a helper function in the Firebase API or do I just write my own code snippet (probably using replace()) to strip out those characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now using `replace()` in some helper function is the best route. There's nothing built into Firebase to deal with the escaping of invalid characters. [This answer is about dealing with emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412393/how-to-index-by-email-in-firebase/24416639#24416639).

```
function escapeEmail(email) {
    return (email || '').replace('.', ',');
}

function unescapeEmail(email) {
    return (email || '').replace(',', '.');
}
```